# Android BuildConfig Issues while adding properties through Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am adding few properties in BuildConfig through build.gradle as below

```
release_prod{
       buildConfig "public static final String ENVIRONMENT = \"prod\";"
    }
    release_dev{
           buildConfig "public static final String ENVIRONMENT = \"dev\";"
    }
```

The problem is when I build from gradle, it works fine but when I compile project in eclipse I get errors because this variable is NOT present in gen BuildConfig.

My question is

1. Is there a way to add few variables in BuildConfig, so that its generated from eclipse at buildtime
2. If NOT, Is there anyway I can generate properties from gradle in a separate file other than BuildConfig.

Answer (score 1):

1. I didn't find a simple way to make Eclipse generate the BuildConfig class.
2. I develop mainly with Eclipse ADT and then release different flavors with Gradle so I came up with the following solution:

   Create my own `CustomBuildConfig` class, add it to Eclipse build path and use Gradle `sourceSets` to select different version of this class.

---

In `Project/build.gradle`, define an additional source folder, specific to a flavor:

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    release_prod {
        java.srcDirs = ['src', 'flavors/prod/src' ]
    }
    release_dev {
        java.srcDirs = ['src', 'flavors/dev/src' ]
    }
}
```

The production env is defined in `Project/flavors/prod/src/CustomBuildConfig.java:`

```
package com.example.project;

public class CustomBuildConfig {
    public static final String ENVIRONMENT = "prod";
}
```

The development env is defined in `Project/flavors/dev/src/CustomBuildConfig.java:`

```
package com.example.project;

public class CustomBuildConfig {
    public static final String ENVIRONMENT = "dev";
}
```

And finally in Eclipse I add only the `Project/flavors/dev/src/` to the build path.